# GridView Within a CustomScrollView

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview

Hello Every one I am having a GridView within a custom ScrollView

Here is the code I am Using
          public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

```
    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

   @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false" );
                    super.onTouchEvent(ev);

                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false" );
                    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false" );
                    return false;

            default: Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action ); break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction() );
         return true;
    }
    }
```

And for the grid view I am adding a touchListener like this

```
    gridview.setOnTouchListener(new GridView.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            scroll.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

where scroll is the reference to the CustomScrollView I have given above

```
    CustomScrollView scroll=(CustomScrollView)findViewById(R.id.page);
```

The Grid View I am Using is displayina a calendar
What is wanted to do is whenever i touch the gridview the events should be transferred to the CustomScrollView 
so that I can scroll to CustomScrollView

It is working but the problem is the screen is flickering a lot when i try to scroll from GridView if I try to scroll from a position above or below the gridview its working fine

Am I missing Something ?
Please Help me guys in deep trouble working on it since a week

Comment: Guys I have just removed `code` super.onTouchEvent(ev); `code` from the Action_down and Acton_CANCEL the flickering has reduced but it is still there a slight flickering

Comment: Guys Any Siggestions on This Is this bcoz too much of work is done on the GridViewAdapter ?